# How to implement an actor topology in AKKA?

Tags: scala, akka, topology

I need to implement various kind of topologies in AKKA actor model system 
    like Line,mesh etc. Are there in built libraries for various kind of topologies
    in AKKA? If not how can I build such topologies? Also, how do we connect two or
    more actors in AKKA because that's the basic for creating any topology?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are describing a solution and not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that topologies make any sense in Akka.

As you have noticed, the basic tool for creating topologies is a connection between two entities. But such connection cannot exist in Akka, because any actor can send a message to any actor. This is the foundation of actor model, after all.

Of course, you can try and emulate some topology manually, but I cannot see any use for it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I get your point and now I am focussing on which actors have to communicate with which other actors rather then creating connections between a particular group, which as you mentioned doesn't make sense in AKKA because of it's open framework.